# Cannot enable matrix in clang-cl in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, clang

I have installed ans selected clang-cl toolset in my project. In C/C++/Command line project settings I entered this: **-fenable-matrix**

Compiler says:

```
1>clang-cl : warning : unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-fenable-matrix' [-Wunknown-argument]
1>main.cpp(3,35): error : matrix types extension is disabled. Pass -fenable-matrix to enable it
```

It literally asks me to add matrix extensions via -fenable-matrix and says that -fenable-matrix is unknown argument. Why?